# How to copy values that have just been deleted into 'Archive' Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets-macros

Setting up so any expired date rows get deleted. But I would Like to Delete and Move to Archive tab(sheet).

Have tried taking other codes and integrating but cannot find the code.

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Current");//assumes Current is the name of the sheet
   var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
   var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
   var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array
   var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);//tomorrow
   for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
       var tempDate = values[i-1][1];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
       if ((tempDate!=NaN) && (tempDate <= currentDate))
       {
           sheet.deleteRow(i);
       }//closes if
   }//closes for loop
}//closes function
```